# file in foreach loop included only once

Tags: php, class, include

I have cronjob script that get data and generate Invoice email and PDF file and sent to user email.

but file pdf.php called only once while i have called function "calculateANDsend()" every time but require file included only once with first data

i need to include pdf.php file every time the same like i call function calculateANDsend in foreach loop

```
#cronjob.php
foreach($data as $user)
{
   $p = new Invoice();
   $p->calculateANDsend($user);
}
```

```
#invoice.php
class Invoice 
{
    public function calculateANDsend($user)
    {
      ...
      //called multiple time this cods and working grate
      require_once "pdf.php";
      ...
    }
}
```

```
#pdf.php
generate TCPDF , pdf file and save
THIS file called only once
```

Comment: `require_once` will only include the file once (hence the name), so either use `require` or put the code into a class and use it that way.

Comment: Yes, but include once every time in the loop the same is when i change require_once to require
i can't put code into class because TCPDF doesn't use namespace and problems get bigger